# Identify the plant

Tags: botany, species-identification

Can anyone tell me which plant or flower is this. I have found it in Darjeeling,  West Bengal, India.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those are known as Rhododendrons, and I'd ID that one as *R. hodgsonii*.